# Find document then get all related documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this mongodb document :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e382d27bb4bd5ce3ef5fb1d"),
    "code" : "25116",
    "datecrea" : "2015-11-14 18:23:24",
    "datemodif" : "2015-11-14 18:23:24",
    "datas" : {
        "songId" : 25116,
        "artistId" : 128,
        "albumId" : 1822,
        "name" : "Free Me",
        "songTrack" : 10,
        "genres" : [ 
            "24"
        ],
    }
}
```

I want to make a request that search for the song by its genre which is an `array` of genres, and then get me the `artist` and the `album` related to this song based on the `datas.artistId` and `datas.albumId` fields.

I have tried this query :

```
db.getCollection('songs').aggregate([
{ $elemMatch: { "datas.genre": 31 } },
{ $lookup: { from: "artists", localField: "datas.artisId", foreignField: "code", as: "artist" } },
{ $unwind: "$artist"}
])
```

But it returns an error, knowing that I totally news to mongodb.
Thanks to everyone for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not far off. You just have two minor syntax errors.

1. The [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), Without going too much into it. `$elemMatch` is not a pipeline stage and cannot be used in an `aggregate` operation. it is typically used in a [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) query.
2. In the lookup you wrote `datas.artisId` instead of `datas.artistId`

So change you're pipeline into this:

```
db.getCollection('songs').aggregate([
    { $match: { "datas.genre": 31 } },
    { $lookup: { from: "artists", localField: "datas.artistId", foreignField: "code", as: "artist" } },
    { $unwind: "$artist"}
])
```

One more fun fact, unrelated to the actual code, the word `data` is already in it's plural form. hence `datas` is a grammatical mistake. And in case you're wondering the singular form of `data` is `datum`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, the problem is that the field `datas.genre`, is an array, and the query I want to make is to search if the value `31` exists in the array, but when I run the `aggregate` function with the `$match` pipeline it returns `0 records`

Comment: Even as an array that syntax works. my guess is no artist is being matched up, then the `$unwind` makes those documents disappear. try running it without the `$unwind` stage or with but use the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` flag for it.

Comment: Also a possibility make sure `31` is stored as a number and not string, or search for `"31"` instead in the case that it's not.

Comment: Thank you so much, is works, there was some field names error "genre" => "genres" and the genre elements are indeed strings

Comment: Good catch, i missed that too!